# SAS - Efficiently delete all integrity constraints from a library

Tags: sas

I have written some code to delete all integrity constraints from a library. However, when I have many tables/libs loaded, reading from sashelp.vtable takes a looong time. How can I do it more efficiently in SAS 9.4, while keeping it simple?

```
%let mv_lib='DL';
data _null_;
    set sashelp.vtable (keep=libname memtype memname) end=eof;
    where libname=&mv_lib. and memtype='DATA';
    if _n_ = 1  then call execute('proc datasets library='||&mv_lib.||' nolist nodetails;');    
                     call execute(catx(' ','modify',memname,'; ic delete _all_; run;'));
    if eof      then call execute('quit;');
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what is happening is that SAS cannot pass the `WHERE` from your data step through the SASHELP.VTABLE view into the actual query to the DICTIONARY.TABLES object so your are querying ALL libnames.

Try using PROC SQL instead.

```
%let mv_lib='DL';
proc sql ;
  create table mylist as
    select libname,memname 
    from dictionary.tables 
    where libname=&mv_lib. and memtype='DATA'
  ;
quit;
data _null_;
  set mylist ;
  ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be dictionary.table**s**? Worked much faster, thank you!

Comment: Right. SASHELP.VTABLE queries DICTIONARY.TABLES